# SQL - how to sum across different rows while having a different equation for the first row

Tags: sql, teradata

I am having trouble figuring how to sum across different rows, but using the first row of each grouping as the starting point.

I have a table that looks like this :

```
+------+------+----------+---------------+----------+-------+
| Dim1 | Dim2 |   Date   | beg_Inventory | purchase | sales |
+------+------+----------+---------------+----------+-------+
| x    | y    | 1/1/2019 |           100 |       50 |    20 |
| x    | y    | 1/2/2019 |               |       70 |    80 |
| x    | y    | 1/3/2019 |               |       40 |    60 |
| x    | y    | 1/4/2019 |               |       30 |    50 |
| x    | y    | 1/5/2019 |               |      100 |    10 |
| x    | z    | 1/1/2019 |            65 |       10 |    50 |
| x    | z    | 1/2/2019 |               |       20 |     5 |
| x    | z    | 1/3/2019 |               |       40 |     5 |
+------+------+----------+---------------+----------+-------+
```

And I want a result that looks like this:

```
+------+------+----------+---------------+----------+-------+------------+
| Dim1 | Dim2 |   Date   | beg_Inventory | purchase | sales | ending_inv |
+------+------+----------+---------------+----------+-------+------------+
| x    | y    | 1/1/2019 |           100 |       50 |    20 |        130 |
| x    | y    | 1/2/2019 |               |       70 |    80 |        120 |
| x    | y    | 1/3/2019 |               |       40 |    60 |        100 |
| x    | y    | 1/4/2019 |               |       30 |    50 |         80 |
| x    | y    | 1/5/2019 |               |      100 |    10 |        170 |
| x    | z    | 1/1/2019 |            65 |       10 |    50 |         25 |
| x    | z    | 1/2/2019 |               |       20 |     5 |         40 |
| x    | z    | 1/3/2019 |               |       40 |     5 |         75 |
+------+------+----------+---------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Ending inventory is beg_inventory + purchase - sales, for the first row in each dim1 and dim2 grouping, i.e. for the first row it is 100+50-20=130
However, in the 2nd row, it has to use the 130 we calculated and use the purchase and sales in the next row to get 130+70-80=120 and so on, grouped by dim1 and dim2 and ordered by date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use `first_value()` to get the first value of `beg_inventory` in the window and than add the windowed `sum()` of purchases and sales to it.

```
SELECT dim1,
       dim2,
       date,
       beg_inventory,
       purchase,
       sales,
       first_value(beg_inventory) OVER (PARTITION BY dim1,
                                                     dim2
                                        ORDER BY date)
       +
       sum(purchase - sales) OVER (PARTITION BY dim1,
                                                dim2
                                   ORDER BY date) ending_inv
       FROM elbat
       ORDER BY dim1,
                dim2,
                date;
```

Comment: Thank you!, when using the above in Teradata I get the 130 replicated for each row. So I had to add "ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING" to the 2nd portion " +
       sum(purchase - sales) OVER (PARTITION BY dim1,
                                                dim2
                                   ORDER BY date) ending_inv"                     I am not really understanding if I should add it to both the 1st and 2nd part of the window function or just the 2nd, and what the difference is.

Comment: Some window functions restrict the rows they look back or forward in the window. With the `ROWS` clause this can be controlled/overridden. I didn't expect Teradata to have such a restriction on `sum()`, sorry. You can add it to both functions, if you want. It might be superfluous when this is already the default for a function, but it won't harm as we want the rows looked back to be unbounded here anyways.

Comment: @Lulumocha: Due to historic reasons (Teradata implemented a predecessor to Standard SQL Windowed Aggregates in 1999) the default for `SUM/etc. OVER (ORDER BY...)` is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, but in Standard SQL it's `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` (which is, btw, not the same as `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` and should be avoided anyway. `FIRST_VALUE` was implemented a few years ago and follows the Standard SQL default, so there's  no need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The formulas for all the rows look the same to me:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(COALESCE(beg_Inventory, 0) + purchase - sales) OVER (PARTITION BY dim1, dim2 ORDER BY date) as ending_inv
FROM t
ORDER BY dim1, dim2, date;
```